# AJAX page load returns [object object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm currently trying to do a simple AJAX page transition in my local host.

Here is the  tag on my home.html

```
<a href="/blank.html">go to blank</a>
```

Should take me to the blank.html page.

Here is my AJAX:

```
$(function(){
  jQuery(function ($) {
      $(document).on('click', "a", function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $.when($("body").fadeOut(1000).promise(), $.ajax({
              url: this.href,
              type: 'get',
              dataType: 'html'
          })).done(function (html) {
              var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
              newDoc.write(html);
              newDoc.close();
              $("body").fadeIn(1000);
          });
      });
  });
});
```

Without the javascript my redirect works fine, but with the javascript, after the fadeOut it returns `[object Object]` on the page (and does not redirect)

I have looked around for a solution but cannot seem to find one.

Any help or advice is appreciated, thank you in advance!

EDIT:

console.log(html); returns:

[image]

Comment: what is the result of `console.log(html)`?

Comment: please see edit! @MaheshSinghChouhan

Comment: what is inside `blank.html`? your ajax request is trying to get normal html content as `dataType:"'html"` but somehow response is throwing an object, that is the issue

Comment: blank.html is just a standard html page, any suggestions on how I could fix? @MaheshSinghChouhan

Comment: try `newDoc.write(html.body);` instead of `newDoc.write(html);`

Comment: so the page now returns "undefined" rather than [object object] @MaheshSinghChouhan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148255/discussion-between-mahesh-singh-chouhan-and-danjonescidtrix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
$(function(){
  jQuery(function ($) {
      $(document).on('click', "a", function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $("body").fadeOut(1000);
          $.ajax({
              url: this.href,
              type: 'get',
              dataType: 'html',
              success: function(html){
                var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
                  newDoc.write(html);
                  newDoc.close();
                  $("body").fadeIn(1000);
              }
          })

      });
  });
});
```